# Transparent background on Image for training CNNs

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, conv-neural-network

I was wondering if having a transparent background for training a CNN affect it learning the features in any way? For example, for training a model to recognize cats, if we were to use only the polygon crop of a cat with a transparent background. Would it learn to recognize cats better?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image-capturing devices are becoming very common, along with object classification software, to such an extent even a simple cellphone can realize state-of-the-art image processing methods.  However,  transparent  objects  do  not  offer  features easy to identify: instead of hiding the background like opaque objects,  they  merely  distort  it.  Therefore,  their  appearance drastically  change  regarding  to  their  environment.  You can think of it as a human would think of it.  Is it easier for a human to recognize an object against an opaque background?  I don't think so.  Also, it's not really natural.  Unless, you see an object embedded in a pile of snow, perhaps.

Comment: You could have put where part of that text comes from though: https://www.cpe.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/How_CNN_grasp_TOf_paper_final_version_2.pdf.

Comment: This answer is not correct and should not have been accepted. Given the cat example, the question is clearly about transparency in the sense of an alpha channel / blending information in an image, e.g. RGBA rather than RGB. The answer (and the context of the plagiarized paper) is clearly about transparency of objects, in that they distort the background behind them, e.g. recognizing a window when it has a mountain behind it (and therefore it distorts the mountain background rather than occluding it).